# Programatiically login to a website that uses IIS authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

Hi all am trying to login to a website programmatically.I have already worked on this but is was a php page and i used the below code (found some where on Stack Overflow) to login to it and it worked great.

```
 private static string GetDataFromPHP(string formUrl, string getUrl, string username, string password, out bool status)
        {

            try
            {

                string formParams = string.Format("access_login={0}&access_password={1}", username, password);
                string cookieHeader;
                WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                req.Method = "POST";
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
                req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }

                WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
                cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
                string pageSource;

                WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
                getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
                WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
                status = true;

                return pageSource;
            }



            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                status = false;
                return string.Empty;
            }

        }
```

Where access_login & access_password is the name of the input box that accepts the credentials.I have no clue how to implement it for a iis Login prompt as shown below.Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can login through a browser and use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to intercept the request, you can use the Fiddler add-on [Request-To-Code](http://www.chadsowald.com/software/fiddler-extension-request-to-code) to generate C# code that will perform the request. The generated code would probably be a good place for you to start at least.

I have successfully used Fiddler with Request-To-Code in similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

Try using HttpWebRequest class and NetworkCredentials classes to accomplish this.

Here is a piece of code that should get you in right direction.

```
// Create Request
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.yourdomain/whatever");

// Create Client
WebClient client = new WebClient();

// Assign Credentials
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");

// Grab Data
string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.yourdomain/whatever");
```

Comment: it throws an (500) Internal Server Error.